# WebStorm 11 JavaScript auto line breaks

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I'm working with Angular2 in WebStorm 11 IDE. When writing HTML in a `.ts` file, WebStorm auto line breaks and adds extra syntax:
[image: view screenshot #1]

What I want is to be able to hit enter after the `h1` and not have WebStorm automatically add the `' + '` syntax to connect the lines....
[image: view screenshot #2]

I can't find anything on google or WebStorm's help page yet.

Answer (score 1):

Go To File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> TypeScript. Then go to the Wrapping and Braces tab. Scroll down to the Binary Expressions section. Select the "Operation sign on next line" option. This seems to work for me, of course I also have this option selected in my JavaScript editor option as well, don't know if that makes a difference

[image]

Comment: hey that was a great idea, but didn't work. Once I hit enter to go to a new line - it adds +' '+ each time i hit enter to break to a new line :( What else you think it could be? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use template strings instead of string literals. The code would compile fine and WebStorm won't add `' + '`.

Comment: Yup that was the key! For anyone else on a mac you can use the alt/option key + tilda for the short cut and it will look like this. `<div>new code here</div>`